# Time based on time zone in C++

Tags: c++, c, time

What is the difference between `gmtime()` and `localtime()` ?
My requirement:
I need to display the time as per the time zone of my place.
I have a time in POSIX(UTC) format in seconds. i have time zone offset(between UTC and my current place) in seconds.
I either add or subtract the time zone offset.
After this i still have the time in POSIX format.
In order to convert it to human time, should I use `gmtime()` or `localtime()`. this is because i need the date too.
Please clarify.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't provide the time zone offset yourself, but rather a real time zone specification via the environment. Then, `localtime` will give you the localized time. (`gmtime` always gives you UTC.) Suppose your code looks like

```
struct tm time_buffer, *localtime;
localtime = localtime_r(timep, &time_buffer);
printf("The hour is %i\n", localtime->tm_hour);
```

, then you call your program via:

```
$ TZ=Europe/Berlin my-program
```

and get the local hour of Berlin, correctly adjusted for daylight saving time.

If you absolutely need to provide a timezone yourself, read `man tzset`.

Answer (score 0):

`gmtime` is UTC—coordinated universal time.  It is always the
same, everywhere.  `localtime` is an interpretation of the local time,
as determined by the time zone and whether summer time is in effect or
not.  The time zone will be determined by the environment variable `TZ`,
which the user should have set to his local timezone; if this variable
is not set, an implementation defined default is used: typically the
timezone where the machine is located.